# How to get li value and print it again

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am creating a website for a university project.
What i have is 3 tables that contain 1 list of links each. The links represent lessons and to what they link it doesn't matter. When a student chooses a lesson then that lesson is supposed to be presented at the bottom of the page without leaving the list.

My code is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> <!--Links the page with my style.css file-->
<body>
<head>
<title>Competences</title>
</head>

<?php
$name = $_GET['name']; 
$surname = $_GET['surname'];
echo "<h3>Hello " .$name." ".$surname"</h3>" ;
?>
<div class="background">
<h5>Below are various competences organised into three main categories. Select the ones you think are more important for your studies by clicking on them.</h5>
<div class="box" style="inline" id="1">
<h2>INSTRUMENTAL</h2>
<ul>
<h4>
<li onClick="Copy()"><a href="#">Capacity for analysis and synthesis</a></li>
<li onClick="Copy()"><a href="#">Capacity for organisation and planning</a></li>
<li onClick="Copy()"><a href="#">Basic general knowledge</a></li>
<li onClick="Copy()"><a href="#">Grounding in basic knowledge of the profession</a></li>
<li onClick="Copy()"><a href="#">Oral and written communication in your native language</a></li>
<li onClick="Copy()"><a href="#">Knowledge of a second language</a></li>
<li onClick="Copy()"><a href="#">Elementary computing skills</a></li>
<li onClick="Copy()"><a href="#">Information management skills (ability to retrieve and analyse information from different sources)</a></li>
<li onClick="Copy()"><a href="#">Problem Solving</a></li>
<li onClick="Copy()"><a href="#">Decision-making</a></li>
</h4>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="box2" style="inline" id="2">
<h2>INTERPERSONAL</h2>
<ul>
<h4>
<li onClick="Copy()"><a href="#">Critical and self-critical abilities</a></li>
<li onClick="Copy()"><a href="#">Teamwork</a></li>
<li onClick="Copy()"><a href="#">Interpersonal skills</a></li>
<li onClick="Copy()"><a href="#">Ability to work in an interdisciplinary team</a></li>
<li onClick="Copy()"><a href="#">Ability to communicate with experts in other fields</a></li>
<li onClick="Copy()"><a href="#">Appreciation of diversity and multiculturality</a></li>
<li onClick="Copy()"><a href="#">Ability to work in an international context</a></li>
<li onClick="Copy()"><a href="#">Ethical commitment</a></li>
</h4>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="box3" style="inline" id="3">
<h2>SYSTEMIC</h2>
<ul>
<h4>
<li onClick="Copy()"><a href="#">Capacity of applying knowledge in practice</a></li>
<li onclick="Copy()"><a href="#">Research Skills</a></li>
<li onClick="Copy()"><a href="#">Capacity to learn</a></li>
<li onClick="Copy()"><a href="#">Capacity to adapt to new situations</a></li>
<li onClick="Copy()"><a href="#">Capacity for generating new ideas(creativity)</a></li>
<li onClick="Copy()"><a href="#">Leadership</a></li>
<li onClick="Copy()"><a href="#">Understanding of cultures and customs of other countries</a></li>
<li onClick="Copy()"><a href="#">Ability to work autonomously</a></li>
<li onClick="Copy()"><a href="#">Project design and management</a></li>
<li onClick="Copy()"><a href="#">Initiative and entrepreneurial spirit</a></li>
<li onClick="Copy()"><a href="#">Concern for quality</a></li>
<li onClick="Copy()"><a href="#">Will to succeed</a></li>
</h4>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<form action="step3.php" method="get">
<input type="submit" value="Submit Choices"/>
</form>


<h5>You have selected the following competences:</h5>

<script type="text/javascript">
var count = new Array();
var i=0;
var column_id = "id";
var col1=0;
var col2=0;
var col3=0;

function Copy()
{
count[i] = "value";
i++;

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '<a href="#"><div>' + count[i] + '</div></a>';

if (column_id==1)
    {
    col1+=1;
    }
 else if (column_id==2)
        {
        col2+=1;
        }
    else if (column_id==3)
            {
            col3+=1;
            }
    div.innerHTML = '<div>'Competences Selected: + col1 + " Instrumental" + col2 + " Interpersonal" + col3 +" Systemic."'</div>';
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also in competences Selected I will have to tell to the student the number of subjects he has selected from Instrumental list, Interpersonal list and Systemic List.

lets say for example my list is that :

Instrumental

1.option1

2.option2

if option 1 is selected as the lesson from instumental then i will have something like:

Competences Selected: 1 Instumental,0 Interpersonal, 0 Systemic

1.option1

As you can see i tried doing it with javascript but i am not quite sure how to make it work.. I don't know if value is what i should take into consideration or if i am supposed to do it with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure what you are doing here, but there are a few things you may want to look at: -

1. In the line `count(i) = "value";` I assume that you are refering to the array. In which case it should be `count[i] = "value"`
2. In the line `"<a href="#"><div>count(i)</div></a>";` I assume that you mean to have the value at the count array index in the div, in which case you want `div.innerHTML = '<a href="#"><div>' + count[i] + '</div></a>';`
3. You have  `onClick="count()"` referencing a count() method but also a global count() array. Change the name of the function to avoid confusion.
4. You have a javascript function called `onclick`, to avoid confusion give it a name that describes what the function does rather than using the generic onclick name.
5. Try to reduce the problem you are having to the smallest subset of self-contained code and you will be more likely to get answers.

*Update:*

Based on your updated code, I think I can see what you are wanting to do. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dL7y2/) for a cut down example, you should be able to apply the same to the rest of the page.

Some notes: -

- calling `count[i] = "value"` will not get you the value of the `<li>` element. You need to pass the element and call innerHTML or retrieve it in the html.
- You actually want the value of the  as far as I can tell, so you might as well put the onclick in the `<a>`.
- calling `var column_id = "id";` will not get you the id of the containing div. You need to first get the div by a selector. I suggest you look into using jQuery to achieve this. For brevity, I just passed the value in the javascript call.
- I left an alert in the Copy() function so you can see what is passed in, you will want to remove this.

Comment: thank you i will do what u suggested. I did do some dumb mistakes, i have been working on that project for hours now and I didn't notice the [] mistake :/ I will fix them , and edit if I have more errors ! Thank you again!

Comment: edited. I hope now is more easy to read and understand. The problem is still there tho. I still can't get the value of <li> or the number of clicks on the links :/